# Facebook Page Plugin doesn't work in IE/Firefox, fine in Chrome

Tags: wordpress, facebook, plugins

I'm hoping someone can help me with this. I have the code for the Facebook Page Plugin (generated here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin) in the sidebar of my WordPress site. You can see it here: http://www.rosekeating.com/ (bottom of the sidebar)

In Chrome (Windows and Mac) it is slow to load, but displays fine. It also works in Safari. But in Firefox and IE, it displays as a blockquote that says "Rose Keating Career Consulting" and the actual Facebook plugin never loads and hides the blockquote.

I can't seem to figure out the issue? Thanks in advance for help...

Comment: Browser console shows an uncaught JavaScript error, and that might prevent any further JS code from getting executed, including the FB code that is supposed to render the plugin.

Comment: I checked in Firefox 39.0 and it seems to render correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but I just encountered this same Facebook plugin problem today with Firefox 53.0 (32-bit).  For me, the fix was to disable Firefox tracking protection for private windows:
`Tools->Options->Privacy->UNCHECK 'Use Tracking Protection in Private Windows'`

Answer (score 0):

Are you perhaps logged in on Chrome on Facebook?

Just had the same issue. Problem was that the page I wanted to use in the Page Plugin was hidden for anonymous users (users that are not logged in to Facebook).

So in Chrome I am logged in by default on Facebook, and I could see the plugin. But in IE I wasn't so the plugin wasn't visible to me.